# Get static JSON single product data in Vue JS by ID

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a Vue JS app which will display a list of products that when clicked on will link through to a dynamic product by its ID (passed via Vue Router params). This bit works fine but what I need to do is once *on* that dynamic route, display all the data for that product by its ID. I'm still pretty new to Vue and confused by what approach to take. I don't think I need axios as this won't be an online app so no access to APIs. I also don't know if I need to go as far as using vuex. At present I'm trying to use a simple method to grab the data from my JSON file by the ID passed through the routes parameters. Here's what I have so far...

**router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import Products from './views/Products.vue'
import Product from './views/ProductSingle.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/products',
      name: 'products',
      component: Products
    },
    {
      path: '/product/:id',
      name: 'product',
      component: Product,
      props: true
    }
  ]
})
```

**Slider.vue** - this component is called in Views/Products.vue and is what links through to each single product

```
<template>
  <carousel
    :items="3"
    :loop="true"
    :center="true"
    :margin="0"
    :dots="false"
    :nav="true"
  >
    <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.productId">
      <transition name="slide">
        <router-link
          :to="{
            name: 'product',
            params: { id: product.productId }
          }"
        >
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city" :alt="product.name" />
          <!-- <img
            :src="require('../assets/images/sample-product/' + data.image)"
          />-->
        </router-link>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </carousel>
</template>

<script>
import json from '@/json/data.json'
import carousel from 'vue-owl-carousel'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: json
    }
  },
  components: {
    carousel
  }
}
</script>
```

ProductSingle.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="product in getData($route.params.id)" :key="product.productId">
      {{ product }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import json from '@/json/data.json'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: json
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData(id) {
      let data = this.products
      data.filter(item => {
        return item.productId == id
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

What I as expecting here is that my getData method would return the data for the product at the ID denoted through `$route.params.id` yet nothing is returned. A console.log(getData($route.params.id)) shows the following:

```
[{…}]
```

Which when expanded out shows `0: {__ob__: Observer}` and if you expand that observer out there is indeed that data for

```
image: (...)
name: (...)
productId: (...)
```

My data.json file looks like the below:

```
[
  {
    "productId": 1,
    "name": "Test 1",
    "image": "sample.jpg"
  },
  {
    "productId": 2,
    "name": "Test 2",
    "image": "sample.jpg"
  },
  {
    "productId": 3,
    "name": "Test 3",
    "image": "sample.jpg"
  },
  {
    "productId": 4,
    "name": "Test 4",
    "image": "sample.jpg"
  }
]
```

Could really do with some guidance on how to approach this problem.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you're never really returning the filtered array in `data.filter(item => {
        return item.productId == id
      })`. You're just filtering the array and then doing nothing with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `return` here:

```
data.filter(item => {
    return item.productId == id
})
```

Try this:

```
return data.filter(item => {
    return item.productId == id
})
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I didn't realise I had to do that, duh! Thank you it seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using Api or Vuex then you need to have all the data on a place where they can be fetched from multiple components.

`data.json` is fine for this.

On your child component, do the following. There is no need for data iteration.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ singleProduct }}
    {{ singleProduct.productId }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import json from '@/json/data.json'

export default {
    name: 'ProductSingle',
  data() {
    return {
      products: json,
      singleProduct: undefined
    }
  },
  computed: {
    productId () {
      return this.$route.params.id // From route
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.assignSingleProduct();
  },
  methods: {
    assignSingleProduct() {
      let data = this.products
      data.filter(item => {
        return item.productId == this.productId
      })

      // Assign to the data
      this.singleProduct = data
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for this comment, in the case where there are sub arrays within the data, I would probably need to loop. For example, all of the products have an array of features - would this be fairly easy to achieve?

Comment: Yes it would. In that case you add v-for="feature in product.features" :) If this solves your issue, please close the question.

Comment: I can't see how to close it - your answer definitely helped but it didn't work as expected. I was still able to take things from the answer tho so thanks!